# Limitations of the splitting construction and SFT

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology

I am trying to understand the so-called symplectic field theory (SFT) machinery used in symplectic topology. As I understand it, one of the applications of SFT (or rather, of the splitting construction) is to the questions of Lagrangian isotopy, as exemplified by [these](https://arxiv.org/abs/0902.0540) [papers](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.08821). Splitting construction allows one to move, in a Hamiltonian fashion, Lagrangian submanifolds to a complement of certain divisor; in the complement of the divisor, the problem typically becomes much easier.

My question is: what are some limitations of SFT or of the splitting construction? Is there an example of a symplectic topological problem where one might naively expect them to be useful but they turn out not to be?

Comment: Perhaps it would also be good to mention the original paper which used neck-stretching to solve a Lagrangian isotopy problem, namely Hind's paper https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0311092 - the idea is not quite the same (disjoining from a divisor) but more like Gromov's proof that Symp(S^2 x S^2) is homotopy equivalent to the Kaehler isometry group (using neck-stretching to put foliations into a nice position with respect to the Lagrangian sphere)

Comment: This is a difficult question to answer because you never know if the
perceived limitations of a method are inherent to the method or if
they are just due to our inability to apply it. For example, there
were many unsuccessful attempts over the years to apply
neck-stretching to prove that all Lagrangian tori in $\mathbf{C}^2$
are Lagrangian isotopic before Dimitroglou Rizell-Goodman-Ivrii
appeared.

Comment: Also, you should bear in mind that neck-stretching is just one tool from the arsenal of symplectic field theory. It's the only one that people tend to use at the moment, because the transversality issues in SFT are still being worked out, whereas compactness for neck-stretching is well-understood. Once we have the full SFT machine, the range of problems to which neck-stretching can contribute will become much wider.

Comment: One more comment: although neck stretching is great for proving Lagrangian isotopy theorems in dimension 4, is also great for other things. For instance, even ignoring its earlier avatars in gauge theory and Riemannian geometry, it was first used in the context of holomorphic curves by Hofer to prove the Weinstein conjecture for the tight S^3. You embed it as a separating hypersurface in CP^2, and pick a sequence of J_t-curves in the class of a complex line (for J_t the neck stretching sequence of almost complex structures) connecting points in the two halves of CP^2. In the limit...

Comment: ...you get a broken curve which then had to be asymptotic to some closed Reeb orbit, so a closed Reeb orbit exists.